# Programmatically write files into HDFS

Tags: hdfs, flume

I am looking at options in Java programs that can write files into HDFS with the following requirements.

1) Transaction Support: Each file, when being written, either fully written successfully or failed totally without any partial file blocks written.

2) Compression Support/File Formats: Can specify compression type or file format when writing contents.

I know how to write data into a file on HDFS by opening a `FSDataOutputStream` shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13457934/writing-to-a-file-in-hdfs-in-hadoop). Just wondering if there is some libraries of out of the box solutions that provides the support I mentioned above.

I stumbled upon Flume, which provides HDFS sink that can support transaction, compression, file rotation, etc. But it doesn't seem to provide an API to be used as a library. The features Flume provides are highly coupled with the Flume architectural components, like source, channel, and sinks and doesn't seem to be usable independently. All I need is merely on the HDFS loading part.

Does anyone have some good suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I think using Flume as "gateway" to HDFS would be good solution. Your program sends data to Flume (using one of interfaces provided by its [sources](http://flume.apache.org/FlumeUserGuide.html#flume-sources)), Flume writes to HDFS.

This way you don't need to support bunch of custom code for interaction with HDFS. On the other hand, you need to install and configure Flume, but in my experience it is much easier (see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16186145/where-does-apache-flume-logs-its-error-messages#comment23166756_16186338) for installation recommendations).

Finally, Flume HDFS sink is open-source component, so you are free to reuse its code under the terms of Apache license. Get the sources here: https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=flume.git;a=tree;f=flume-ng-sinks/flume-hdfs-sink;h=b9414a2ebc976240005895e3eafe37b12fad4716;hb=trunk